# center nav-pills on page but have fixed position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a set of nav-pills that I will display at the bottom of the window in @media (max-width: 767px) and at the top of the screen at @media (min-width: 768px)  Below is the nav-pills. I can make it center without issue.  If I add position fixed and put it at the bottom of the page I am no longer able to use the inline-block with the text-align center.

How can I have the nav-pills both centered and fixed to a certain height?

HTML

```
<ul id="thisMenu" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#thisMenu > li {
    float:none!important;
    display:inline-block!important;
}

#thisMenu {
    text-align:center!important;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ojuyam/1/edit

This jsbin shows it at the bottom of the page, but not centered. (also does not stick to bottom of the window, it sticks to bottom of the page.)

http://jsbin.com/ojuyam/5/edit

Comment: some thing like this? http://jsbin.com/ojuyam/2/edit

Comment: adding the clear made the nav-pills not centered any more. I added a bottom attribute to throw it to the bottom. http://jsbin.com/ojuyam/5/edit, however still not centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give it a width. If you add `width: 100%;` it will work. See http://jsbin.com/ojuyam/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#thisMenu {
    width: 148px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -74px;
}
```

So would this:

```
#thisMenu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```